# What is the fastest and/or better way to use getSymbols()? To get each equity separate or all together?

Tags: r, quantmod

Let's assume that you would like to get the data from a lot of equities (>100) from Yahoo and Alpha Vantage (AV) since 2000.

I was wondering if somebody did investigate any of the following 2 questions:

**1)** What is **faster** when using getSymbols()? To get each equity separate or all together in one call to getSymbols()?

**2)** What would be **less error prone**? Separate calls or one call with all the equities?

Thanks for any help or suggestion in any of the 2 points.

HL

Comment: I'm asking this because, from time to time, I get an error from AV. And if I run getSymbols() a few minutes later it's fine.
Right now, for every equity name, I'm calling getSymbols() one by one.

Answer (score 3):

Why not something like the following which will drag in the whole SP500, then you can just filter by `ticker`.

```
library(BatchGetSymbols)

first.date <- Sys.Date()-365
last.date <- Sys.Date()

df.SP500 <- GetSP500Stocks()
tickers <- df.SP500$tickers

l.out <- BatchGetSymbols(tickers = tickers,
                         first.date = first.date,
                         last.date = last.date)

print(l.out$df.control)
print(l.out$df.tickers)

df <- l.out$df.control
df2 <- l.out$df.tickers

library(tidyquant)
df2 %>% 
  filter(ticker == "GOOG") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = ref.date, y = price.close)) +
  geom_line() +
  labs(title = "GOOG Line Chart", y = "Closing Price", x = "") + 
  theme_tq()
```

I am sure `tidyquant` has a function to grab the whole SP500 also.

Comment: It's a good suggestion when working with an all index. Sadly, in my case, I'm working with equities from different indexes and different countries. And, from time to time, I get an error from AV.